# adding custom border drawable to android RelativeLayout not showing - Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xml, xamarin.android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to add a **background rectangle shape** to a custom RelativeLayout in android and I'm following the recommendations of most questions on here by implementing a custom drawable in `customborder.xml` and setting it as the background of the `custom.axml` view. I have also tried setting the relativeLayout source as well.

You can see I've also tried it in an imageView which isn't showing up either.

I've messed around with size and color but nothing appears to be rendered.

Am I missing something that needs to be done in code? Or the xml?

**customborder.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    shape="rectangle">
    <corners radius="20dp"/>
    <padding left="50dp" right="50dp" top="50dp" bottom="50dp"/>
    <stroke width="10dp" color="#B2F7FE"/>
    <solid color="white"/>
 </shape>
```

**custom.axml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/customborder">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageViewBackground"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="49.0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#ffededed"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:alpha="1"
    android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
    android:foreground="@drawable/customborder" />
<refractored.controls.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10.5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="24dip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46.0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12.0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FF7F3300"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You just need to apply android prefix with every element in customborder.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your customborder.xml file with following code,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
<padding
    android:bottom="50dp"
    android:left="50dp"
    android:right="50dp"
    android:top="50dp" />
<stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#B2F7FE"/>
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Your mistake was android prefix is missing.Also you are missing close tag in your layout.